Empty not following the rest of the items when moving them
In the creation of a kinamatic, I've chosen to use an  empty 'add IK / to an empty'.
I create a bezier circle. At this point I can select everything, using G, I move everything and it stays as it should.
Using  constraints, with bezier as the object,  and then object/clear/ location
and the empty will follow the bezier circle,  but...
If I select everything, then use G, everything moves, except the empty does not move in unison with everything else.
The empty moves, but not in sync with everything else.

hello, it's hard to understand, could you please share your file or at least show some screenshots? Maybe you need to parent your empty?
